# Return and get object in one class

Tags: php, sql, object

I am unable to write a code to get object for another function.

I have one class called `RepairsService` where I have two functions.

First `createRepair($request, $vehicle)` is where I create object.

```
public function createRepair($request, $vehicle)
    {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle) {

            Log::info('Creating new repair.');

            $repair = new Repair();
            $repair->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;

            DB::insert('insert into repairs (vehicle_id) values (?)', 
                    [$repair->vehicle_id]); 
        });
       $this->addRepair($request, $vehicle, $this); //here I call second function trying to pass $this parameter as object 
    }
```

And second in the same class is

```
public function addRepair($request, $vehicle, $repair){

        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $repair) {

            $workers_needed->repair_id = $repair->id;  //I need to get this id from the object 
            $workers_needed->worker_id = $request->worker_id;

            DB::insert('insert into repair_worker (repair_id, worker_id) values (?, ?)',
                    [$workers_needed->repair_id, $workers_needed->worker_id]);

            Log::info('Repair created.');
            flash('Repair successfully added.', 'success');
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Right now using this code, I am getting error 
`Undefined property: App\Models\Repairs\RepairsService::$id` what makes sense, since I am not passing object (I think).

**UPDATE:**

So the main problem described above is fixed in the following code, but I am heading a very little problem now. In the second function, I am trying to assign `$repair-id` to `$workers_needed->repair_id` but I get `NULL` value there. I have tried to assign value `1` (hard coded) instead of using `$repair-id` but it seems that my second function call runs before the first function is done with `transaction` which makes sense, because as far as I know, `transaction` inserts data only if everything goes well and in this case, it is waiting for second function to get its work done. So the `repair` instance is not inserted into database. How can I edit the code so the transaction gets done and then I call my second function? Or is there another way how to do it?

```
public function createRepair($request, $vehicle)
    {
        $repair = null;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $repair) {

            Log::info('Creating new repair.');

            $repair = new Repair();
            $repair->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;

            DB::insert('insert into repairs (vehicle_id) values (?)', 
                    [$repair->vehicle_id]); 
            $this->addRepairWorker($request, $vehicle, $repair);
        });
    }


    public function addRepairWorker(Request $request , Vehicle $vehicle, Repair $repair){

        $workers_needed = null;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $repair) {

            Log::info('Creating new repair worker instance.');

            $workers_needed = new Repair_worker();
            $workers_needed->repair_id = $repair->id;
            $workers_needed->worker_id = $request->worker_id;

            DB::insert('insert into repair_worker (repair_id, worker_id) values (?, ?)',
                    [$workers_needed->repair_id, $workers_needed->worker_id]);

            Log::info('Repair created.');
            flash('Repair successfully added.', 'success');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it not be;

```
public function createRepair($request, $vehicle)
{
    $repair = null;
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $repair) {

        Log::info('Creating new repair.');

        $repair = new Repair();
        $repair->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;

        DB::insert('insert into repairs (vehicle_id) values (?)', 
                [$repair->vehicle_id]); 
    });
   $this->addRepair($request, $vehicle, $repair);
}
```

This is because you are expecting a `repair` instance in that function call.

Additionally, you are using an anonymous function so you have to declare `repair` outside of the scope and declare it for the function using `use`.

**UPDATE**

In order to accommodate for the new error, you need to `commit()` the transaction in order for it to updated/inserted. More information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php).

```
DB::transaction(...);
DB::commit(); // This is where the query actually gets sent to the database
```

As you are rolling your own `DB` wrapper you may have to write the method yourself, an example of using `PDO` is below;

```
class DB {
    ...
    public function commit() {

        return $PDO->commit();
    }
    ...
}
```

Commit returns a `bool` on success/failure so you can rollback if `false` or proceed when `true`.

Comment: Good point about the anonymous function. I'd probably move the second method call to inside the function.

Comment: Ye I agree, or even have `$repair` as a member of the enclosing class.

Comment: If I edit my code like @jeroen said, + I add `$repair = null;` I get this error `Argument 1 passed to App\Models\Repairs\RepairsService::addRepair() must be an instance of App\Models\Repairs\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\app\Models\Repairs\RepairsService.php on line 26 and defined` and line 26 is function call `$this->addRepair..`

Comment: @Ady96 You need to use the correct namespaces / class names for the type hints. And pass the correct variables ;-)

Comment: The error code explains what is happening you are giving it an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` whilst you required it to have an instance of `App\Models\Repairs\Request`

Comment: @nevabyte okay so I have worked it out a bit, but I got stuck with another problem described in my updated question. Thanks for help

Comment: I have updated my answer to help with your current problem. If anymore problems persist I would suggest writing a new question and marking one of the answers on this question as correct

Comment: @nevabyte  Thanks, `commit` worked, I get data into DB but even though I am still gettin `NULL` value for `$workers_needed->repair_id`.

Comment: @nevabyte Because function call is inside `transaction`, `$repair` has still `NULL` value so it will never have object for function call passed correctly, it will be always `NULL`.

Comment: I would post a new question and accept one of the answers here. The questions/answers/comments are quite convoluted and would be hard for others to follow.

Comment: Okay, I have created new one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664807/return-object-by-function-before-second-function-call

Answer (score 0):

In your first method in class `RepairsService` you call your second method like this:

```
$this->addRepair($request, $vehicle, $this);
```

`$this` is an instance of `RepairsService` but in your second method it seems that you expect an object of class `Repair` there.

So you should probably call your second method using the object you just instantiated in the first method:

```
$this->addRepair($request, $vehicle, $repair);
```

In general it would be useful to add [type-hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) so that you can catch these mistakes directly. Your second method would look for example something like:

```
public function addRepair(Request $request, Vehicle $vehicle, Repair $repair){
    ...
```

Assuming that I have your class names right...

Now your IDE should tell you that you are doing something wrong before you even run the code.

**Edit:** Note that if you want to use type-hinting (you should...), you need to use the correct classes.

So in your case it might very well be something like:

```
public function addRepair(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, Vehicle $vehicle, Repair $repair){
    ...
```

But in the end it depends on what objects you want to pass and what classes they belong to exactly.

Comment: I am getting `undefined variable $repair`  in the function call line  `$this->addRepair...`

Comment: @Ady96 See the other answer about the other problem you have; you should use that or put the second method call inside the anonymous function.

Comment: anonymous function?

Comment: @Ady96 `DB::transaction(function () ...`. The function in your method without a name.

Comment: I have updated my question with some questions I mentioned in comments.

Comment: I just tried it but not working. It still expects `Argument 1 passed to App\Models\Repairs\RepairsService::addRepair() must be an instance of App\Models\Repairs\Illuminate\Http\Request` with the edit you suggested.

Comment: @Ady96 Do you use an IDE? Namespaces should be added automatically. Anyway, I added a backslash before `Illuminate`.

Comment: Yea, now it seems we have moved on, but in this case another error showed up, `Argument 3 passed to App\Models\Repairs\RepairsService::addRepair() must be an instance of App\Models\Repairs\Repair, null given` where function call is outside 
 of anonymous function as I have in my edited queston. Does it have to do something with the `use` ?

Comment: Thanks, this part seems fine now, but I have updated my question with hopefully last problem, `NULL` value in `$repair->id` ..